# use powershell to bring a background process to foreground

Tags: powershell, background-process

I start the everything.exe program and shut down the window interface.In this case, everything.exe becomes a background process.

Now I want to turn the everything.exe into a foreground process, open the everything window and be the focus.

What powershell command should I use to implement this requirement?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Show the code how you start the exe and hide its window.

Comment: I double click the Everything.exe file and click the X button to close the window. But the everything process is still existing. When I double click the Everything icon in the hidden area of the taskbar，the window pop up. I want to pop up window with powershell commands, not double-click icon.

Comment: Absent an exposed API provided by the program which can show/hide the active window, you would need to implement UI automation if you need to physically click the taskbar icon. While not impossible, it may not be worth the effort. There is not an "easy" way to implement this.